# JavaFX: pause transition, not equal times

Tags: animation, javafx-2, javafx

I have written a small application that performs some long-running tasks. Instead of having the user to wait and seeing just a progress bar, I would like to display some (changing) information about the application.

For that purpose, I wrote the following code within the constructor of an extended `Pane`:

```
FadeTransition fadeOutTransition = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(1000), this);
fadeOutTransition.setFromValue(0.8);
fadeOutTransition.setToValue(0.0);
```

Similarly the `fadeInTransition`. And further...

```
SequentialTransition seqTransition = new SequentialTransition (
      new Transition() {
         { setInterpolator(Interpolator.DISCRETE);
           setCycleDuration(Duration.seconds(1)); }

           protected void interpolate(double frac) {
               int nextElement = (int) ((explenations.size() - 1) * Math.random());

               Explenation explenation = explenations.get(nextElement);
               questionLabel.setText(explenation.getQuestion());
               answerLabel.setText(explenation.getAnswer());
           }
       },
       fadeInTransition,
       new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(15)),
       fadeOutTransition
);
```

What I woud like is the text to fade in, stay there for ~15 seconds and then fade out again. Unfortunately, the animation flickers, moves faster and slower - and the `PauseTransition` never takes 15 seconds! What is wrong about the code? I'm using Java 7, and JavaFX 2.2 on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that I called the function

```
seqTransition.play();
```

multiple times. From there comes probably the flickering and the unequal waiting time.